# How to override Magento 2 framework file?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides

I try to override this file :

```
vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php
```

I create a module.xml, registration.php and di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" type="MyNamespace\MagentoFramework\Model\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" />
</config>
```

My override class :

```
namespace MyNamespace\MagentoFramework\Model\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link;

    class Current extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current
    {
        /**
         * Get href URL
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getHref()
        {
            return $this->getUrl($this->getPath());
        }
    }
```

The module is enable but this file doesn't override the original.

Do you have any suggestions ?
Thanks !

Comment: Why you overwrite the whole class?

Comment: I need to override getHref() and _toHtml() method of Current class. 
this is not the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the link
[How to Override Framework Class in Magento 2](https://magecomp.com/blog/override-framework-class-magento-2/)

They are following the same folder structure in custom namespace or module section.

You can try the same logic without introducing additional folders [model/framework]

OR

You can implement plugin to overwrite the function.

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current">
    <plugin name="customermgmt_index_plugin" type="Devi\Customview\Plugin\Current" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
</config>
```

Current.php ( Plugin File )

namespace Devi\Customview\Plugin;

```
class Current
{

  public function afterGetHref()
  {
    echo 'plugin working';

   }
 }
```

Please check and let me know whether its solving your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the model/framework folders but it still does not work. Do I need to run specific commands ?

Comment: you can delete the files inside generated folder and clean your cache and try again

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work...

Comment: you can use the plugin to overwrite the specific function. I have updated the answer with code also.

Comment: Plugin solution works, but not for protected method like **_toHtml()**

Answer (score 0):

<s>In your `etc/module` sequence you should put the `Magento_Framework`</s>

To make sure you have the right order of module dependencies.

UPDATE:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" type="MyNamespace\MagentoFramework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" />
</config>
```

Note: Make sure to put the `Current.php` inside `View\Element\Html\Link` directory

Comment: In the file app/code/MyNamespace/MagentoFramework/etc/module.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyNamespace_MagentoFramework" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>

Comment: yes in that file you do sequence

Comment: What do you mean by "sequence" ? Something is missing in this file ?

Comment: check updated answer . it should be like that in your module.xml

Comment: just change Vendor_Module with your custom module

Comment: Ok, module name in sequence should be "Magento_Framework" or "MagentoFramework" ?

Comment: Magento_Framework

Comment: Thanks, But it still does not work.

Comment: ah I think it is not Magento_Framework I cant check bcause Im only using mobile

Comment: Do you know how can I check this ?

Comment: cant really tell

Comment: updated My answer, maybe check again if current.php file is in the right path

Comment: Yes it's in the right path : 
app/code/MyNamespace/MagentoFramework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php

Comment: instead of className only can you put exact file name in preference, I mean try to put .php on each Current class name

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid Document Element 'preference', attribute 'for': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current.php' is not accepted by the pattern[...]

Comment: oh so it is not allowed

Comment: try to copy all codes in current.php  and make changes for methods you want to override

Comment: Yes I try but it does not work. Should I run some commands ? I try upgrade, clean cache, flush cache

Comment: yeah try upgrade, deploy static files then indexer

Comment: I tried all of these commands, still nothing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92390/discussion-on-answer-by-magefms-how-to-override-magento-2-framework-file).

Answer (score 0):

After following this article [How to Override Framework Class in Magento 2](https://magecomp.com/blog/override-framework-class-magento-2/), The override works for this file :

```
vendor/magento/framwork/View/Page/Title.php
```

but not for this file :

```
vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php
```

Do you know if this file can not be overridden ?

Answer (score 0):

We can override using preference.

- Create di.xml
- Create class php file

  ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader" type="NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader" />
  ```
- In the given path put your fle `NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader`