# Magento2 - Product Attribute Not reindex error

Tags: php-7.2, magento2.3.4-p2

[image]

I can't get SKU name for the title tag because of the not index product attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP error is because of the deprecated functionality `implode` as on `PHP 7.4.x`

> 8.0.0 Passing the separator after the array is no longer supported.
>
> 7.4.0 Passing the separator after the array (i.e. using the legacy signature) has been deprecated.

You need to replace the line in the file `Magento\Framework\DB\Sql\UnionExpression` inside the method `__toString()` through `Plugins` or through `preferences`

```
$sql = implode($parts, $this->type);
```

with

```
$sql = implode($this->type, $parts);
```

As you can see the arguments for `implode` have been interchanged (swapped), which is the expected order of arguments as of `PHP 7.4.0.`

To properly override the respective Magento Framwework file, check the one below

[How to override Magento 2 framework file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269895/how-to-override-magento-2-framework-file)

[PHP implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)